# Homotopy type of $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ \mathrm{wedge \hspace{3pt} sum \hspace{3pt} of \hspace{3pt} 2 \hspace{3pt} circles} \}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is there something "nice" that the space $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ \mathrm{wedge \hspace{3pt} sum \hspace{3pt} of \hspace{3pt} 2 \hspace{3pt} circles} \}$ is homotopy equivalent to? I know that $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{\mathrm{circle}\} \simeq S^{2} \vee S^{1}$, and that $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ \mathrm{2 \hspace{3pt} linked \hspace{3pt} circles}\} \simeq S^{2} \vee T^{2}$. However, I can't seem to apply either of the "visual methods" used to prove these homotopy equivalences to my case.

My wild guess is that it might be homotopic to $M_{2}$, the orientable closed surface of genus $2$, but I'm not sure if this is true at all.

Comment: Hmm, I'd imagine that the proof of $\mathbb R^3\setminus S^1\simeq S^2\wedge S^1$ would generalize ...

Comment: Get a big sphere around them and draw $2$ diameters?

Comment: Obviously not diamaters, but... I'll check it out.

Comment: In general, if you remove a wedge of $n$ circles from $\mathbb{R}^3$, then what is remaining is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of $S^2$ and $n$ circles.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the proof for $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus S^{1} \simeq S^{2} \vee S^{1}$ works, I just didn't "visualize it hard enough"! Thanks!

Comment: Depends wildly on the way the circles are embedded.

Comment: In a coplanar way. Consider them both in the $Oxy$ plane.